# Asp.Net Core 2 (full framework) deployment to IIS creates an unwanted folder on the disk root

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I have deployed a Asp.Net Core 2 app to IIS. The app is running fine but it keeps creating the following directory structure in the disk root:
D:\MYAPPNAME\MYAPPNAME\1.0.0

Even if i manually delete the folder, it gets created again when the app runs. What may cause this behaviour?

**EDIT**
After further investigation, i reproduced the issue using the VS 2017 template for asp-net core2 mvc application.

After adding Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.TraceSource nuget package and configuring  the logs in app.config the unwated folder gets created...

This is the relevant part of the App.config

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="TestApp" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <clear />
          <add name="RotatingFileLog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="Microsoft" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <clear />
          <add name="RotatingFileLog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="RotatingFileLog" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" initializeData="FileLogWriter" logFileCreationSchedule="Daily" traceOutputOptions="DateTime" BaseFileName="test" location="Custom" CustomLocation="E:\logs\test\" Delimiter="|" AutoFlush="True" Append="True"></add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <clear />
        <add name="RotatingFileLog" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: You need to give us a clue about what your code should be doing...

Comment: @Dragonthoughts It is not my code which creates the folder. I believe it is the asp.net-core runtime or the AspNetCoreModule for IIS

Comment: No. It *is* your code, even if that just amounts to the configuration for the trace logging. Out of the box, ASP.NET Core does not create a folder like this. Something you've added is doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has turned out that Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener was creating the folder. I switched to another listener, in this case Essential.Diagnostics.RollingFileTraceListener